# Class 'User' not found

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

So I'm trying a basic `php artisan db:seed` after migrating my database but it keeps returning the title error in cmd -`[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException] Class 'User' not found`

**Things I Have Tried**

- php dump-autoload after updating the class
- php dump-autoload before running the `db:seed` function
- rolling back the migration and then re-running it
- rolling back the migration and then re-running it with the `--seed` syntax
- Change the namespace of the 'Users' File

**Below is the migrations**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password', 60);
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('users');
    }
}
```

I believe that everything here is correct, and now here is the **user class**.

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;

class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, CanResetPasswordContract {

    use Authenticatable, CanResetPassword;

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'users';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'password'];

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token'];

}
```

And now lastly is the all important **database seeder**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        Model::unguard();

        // $this->call('UserTableSeeder');
        $this->call('UserTableSeeder');

        Model::reguard();
    }
}

class UserTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {

        DB::table('users')->delete();

        User::create(['email' => 'John@doe.com']);

    }
}
```

So that's it my full syntax, if any more files are required then please request them and I will update my question.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In your `DatabaseSeeder` in the root namespace you call the Class `User`. It therefor tries to load the class `User`. The definition of your class `User` is however in namespace `App`. You should therefor use either `App\User` in your `DatabaseSeeder` or add at the top of the file `use App\User;`

`DatabaseSeeder`

```
<?php

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        Model::unguard();

        // $this->call('UserTableSeeder');
        $this->call('UserTableSeeder');

        Model::reguard();
    }
}

class UserTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {

        DB::table('users')->delete();

        User::create(['email' => 'John@doe.com']);

    }
}
```

Since Laravel 8+ the User class is now stored by default in the `app/Models` directory; so instead of using `App\User` use `App\Models\User` above.

Ps. by default Laravel ships with a User model, use that one. In case you removed that model you can use the fallback provided by Laravel:

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User;
```

On a side note something I find very useful in order to debug artisan output. You should use the flag `-vvv` which adds extreme verbosity to the output messages including a complete stack trace.

```
php artisan migrate -vvv
```

Comment: if `use App\User;` not works then put it like this `use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User;`.

Comment: @AshwaniPanwar Thank you that was my issue and fixed it for me!

Comment: `use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User;` is what i neeeded

Comment: Thanks @AshwaniPanwar I had to add this line to `DatabaseSeeder.php` and `UsersTableSeeder.php` using Laravel 5.8.38. Greetings